# LLVM/Clang++ cannot find <iostream>

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++

My environment:

- System: Windows 10
- LLVM: 12.0.0 (pre-built) with clang 12.0.0 (posix)
- MinGW-W64: 4.3.4 (pre-built) with gcc 7.3.0 (posix)

Both of MinGW-W64 and LLVM are added to my PATH.
When I try to compile my Hello-World with clang++, it yells:

```
clang++: warning: unable to find a Visual Studio installation; try running Clang from a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]
test1.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

When I add `-v`, it does not search the g++ stdlib:

```
clang version 12.0.0
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: D:\.llvm12\bin
clang++: warning: unable to find a Visual Studio installation; try running Clang from a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]
clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-stdlib=libc++' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
 "D:\\.llvm12\\bin\\clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.11.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -mincremental-linker-compatible --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name test1.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=none -fmath-errno -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -v -resource-dir "D:\\.llvm12\\lib\\clang\\12.0.0" -internal-isystem "D:\\.llvm12\\lib\\clang\\12.0.0\\include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir "D:\\.tmp" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length=120 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fms-compatibility-version=19.11 -std=c++14 -fdelayed-template-parsing -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\test1-4517aa.o" -x c++ test1.cpp
clang -cc1 version 12.0.0 based upon LLVM 12.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 D:\.llvm12\lib\clang\12.0.0\include
End of search list.
test1.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Have I installed the wrong version of LLVM or MinGW-W64?

Edit 1:
I try to use `--target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu` to compile an obviously wrong piece of code:

```cpp
// test3.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Then it gives me a satisfying response:

```
test3.cpp:4:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'; did you mean 'std::cout'?
        cout << "\n";
        ^~~~
        std::cout
D:\.mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.3.0\include\c++\iostream:61:18: note: 'std::cout' declared here
  extern ostream cout;          /// Linked to standard output
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

I want to add `--target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu` to my default settings. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, Clang operates in MSVC-compatible mode by default, using its standard library and various headers.

To make it operate in MinGW-compatible mode, add following flag: `--target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu`. Or, if you compile for x32 bits instead of x64, replace `x86_64` with `i686`.

Alternatively, uninstall your Clang (and MinGW as well) and reinstall them from MSYS2. Their build of Clang uses this flag by default. Also, the version of GCC they provide is more recent than yours (10.3 vs 7.3).

Also, judging by `-stdlib=libc++`, you're trying to use libc++ on Windows. I don't think the official Clang build provides it for Windows, but MSYS2 folks do.

Comment: I tried both of `stdlib=libc++` and using MSYS2, but they result the same.

Comment: ```c
// test3.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
 cout << "\n";
 return 0;
}
```
To verify your solution, I tried to compile this code full of error with `--target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu`, and I am satisfied with its response:
```
test3.cpp:4:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'; did you mean 'std::cout'?
        cout << "\n";
        ^~~~
        std::cout
D:\.mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.3.0\include\c++\iostream:61:18: note: 'std::cout' declared here
  extern ostream cout;          /// Linked to standard output
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: @TeddyLi Okay, just do what it says? Replace `cout` with `std::cout`?

Comment: Of course I know it. I just want to add `--target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu` to my default settings. I am new to stackoverflow so forgive me for making the format a mess.

Comment: @TeddyLi Ah, ok. If you compile directly from the console, you have to specify the flag every time. If you use some kind of an IDE or a build system, you can just put the flag in there. Or, as I said, you can reinstall the compiler from MSYS2, and have this flag by default.

Comment: I have an msys2 environment (abandoned, however [doge]). Which file should I edit?

Comment: @TeddyLi As I said, Clang installed from MSYS2 uses this flag by default. If it doesn't work for you, reinstall MSYS2 from scratch (don't forget to remove any other versions of MinGW or Clang first, just in case), and edit your question to explain how exactly you do it step by step.

Comment: OK I'll try. Anyway, using batch scripts is also a good idea.